# Jupyter and Spyder behaviors are different

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have the following data as an example:

```
data = (
        [1,230.1,37.8,69.2,22.1],
        [2,44.5,39.3,45.1,10.4],
        [3,17.2,45.9,69.3,9.3],
        [4,151.5,41.3,58.5,18.5],
        [5,180.8,10.8,58.4,12.9],
        )
```

I use the same code on Spyder and Jupyter notebook, but I receive a different output, e.g.:

If I enter `data` (without `print()`) in Spyder, I receive no output, just new line, but if I enter `data` (without `print()` as well) in Jupyter, I receive the full data in the output

```
([1, 230.1, 37.8, 69.2, 22.1],
 [2, 44.5, 39.3, 45.1, 10.4],
 [3, 17.2, 45.9, 69.3, 9.3],
 [4, 151.5, 41.3, 58.5, 18.5],
 [5, 180.8, 10.8, 58.4, 12.9],
 )
```

The only way to get the output in Spyder is to use the `print()` command

```
print(data)



([1, 230.1, 37.8, 69.2, 22.1], [2, 44.5, 39.3, 45.1, 10.4], [3, 17.2, 45.9, 69.3, 9.3], [4, 151.5, 41.3, 58.5, 18.5], [5, 180.8, 10.8, 58.4, 12.9])
```

Also you can see the difference between the output format in both cases

1- Can someone please example why the difference in behavior?

2- Can I set up Spyder to behave the same way Jupyter notebook is behaving?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to follow from your post where you are entering your code in Spyder? If you want it to be more like Jupyter, you want to use IPython. That is usually running in the console in the bottom left when you start things up, see the image [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spyder-ide/spyder/5.x/img_src/screenshot.png) where it says 'IPython Console'. Current Jupyter `.ipynb` files using the Python kernel evolved from IPython, first as IPython notebooks, and then Jupyter when it added the ability to run different languages than IPython. The REPL ability that IPython added was a ...

Comment: <continued> a significant improvement from the console/interpreter you got when you just enter `python` on the command line. Beyond the Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop  (REPL), IPython added magic commands and things and then IPython notebook and Jupyter continued to take it further, adding more features & handling recognized types of output better, etc.. So the answer to '1' is probably the REPL. I suspect you are running code in the main coding block in Spyder and that just uses Python, which doesn't have the REPL or specialness of last line. The last line in IPython and Jupyter gets the output ...

Comment: <continued> representation of that type of object displayed, without you needing to use `print()` or `display()`. Behind-the-scenes IPython and Jupyter are usually set by default to try to handle representing output types by those methods as best can be done. You don't get that in Python because you just have core Python loaded there and you have to specify things. For your question '2' at the bottom, check out [this Spyder-notebook plugin](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/plugins/notebook.html#:~:text=Spyder%2Dnotebook%20is%20a%20plugin,Variable%20explorer%2C%20console%20and%20debugger.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### In regards to '1' at the bottom of your post:

I think the main summary to address #1 is that **in IPython and Jupyter, the last line is special**. IPython/Jupyter will try to represent what is on the last line in an entered block of code (IPython) or cell (Jupyter) as best considered in the ecosystem. (It comes from the '- print -' part of the REPL model. It will try to 'print' what the last line is. I am purposefully putting the word *print* in quotes here as 'print' in Jupyter model can mean represent it nicely because it has more abilities in the interface.) Python doesn't have that feature so you have to tell it how to handle what you consider the result by specifying how to display it. Usually you just use `print()` as you do in your example. (I added some information in my comments to your post on the evolution that may help you understand things in the context of the ecosystem and what to expect in each situation.)
One of the biggest differences is Pandas dataframes handling, if you've come across them. Jupyter has nice representation of them without you needing to anything & party that is only possible because it is in a browser. In Python you have to tell it how and what specifically to display in regards to the dataframe, and it will just be purely text-based in the text based interface.
Plots are another similar one for Jupyter where it displays them nicely right in the interface. However, handling these has evolved further in Jupyter recently so that no longer does this have to be invoked on the last line to trigger 'print'-like handling for the plot, as these days Juptyer will try to display a plot object made in a Jupyter cell if it properly detects one has been made. (You'll see a lot of outdated code suggesting that you need to invoke showing it on the last line by referencing the plot or something like `plt.show()` and sometimes it is good to try that when troubleshooting, but mostly it is not needed now. So it kind of confuses the paradigm of output handling with the last line being important.) By contrast, in Python you have to have something set up to handle displaying a plot, such as installing Qt so it will trigger displaying it to a Qt window or use your Python code to send the plot object to an image file, and then view that on your system as you would view any other image file.

##### In regards to '2' at the bottom of your post:

Check out [the Spyder-notebook plugin](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/plugins/notebook.html#:%7E:text=Spyder%2Dnotebook%20is%20a%20plugin,Variable%20explorer%2C%20console%20and%20debugger.).

Comment: Thanks Wayne for your explanation in such details, it is highly appreciated, I did not know that I can use the console, I thought it is for output display only, (learning), I also installed the plugin and will start working on it. Thanks again

Comment: The console can be very handy to query the current namespace. In Spyder if you define a variable in the main scripting window and run it, say `a = 3`, then over in the console you can type `a` and see it that is is `3`. That's a very simple example, but hopefully gives you a sense that it can really help with developing and debugging. JupyterLab has similar abilities; try it by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and pressing 'launch binder'. When you open a new notebook, you'll see you can also attach a console to the namespace of that notebook ==> Right-click ...

Comment: <continued> in a cell in the new notebook, and then select 'New Console for Notebook'. It will open a console window. You can click and drag on it's tab to arrange it wherever you feel best for working relative the open notebook. It is one of the many ways in JuptyerLab you customize what you see as you code and run things, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/console-would-not-automatically-run-code-typed-in-notebook-kernel/12512/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-have-new-printouts-at-top-of-cell/12683/2?u=fomightez).